# Change placeholder alignment in MDCTextField with MDCTextInputControllerUnderline iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, material-design, mdc-components

Is it posible to change the placeholder text alignment in a MDCTextField that is using MDCTextInputControllerUnderline?

What I am looking for is despite the placeholder appears like this:

```
Place holder

.............................
```

I want it at the middle

```
      Place holder

.............................
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hi, did you manage to fix that? 2019 and this still bugs me and can't seem to find good solution

Comment: Hi, any solutions?

Comment: Hi haven't tested that but it looks like there is not any solution. https://github.com/material-components/material-components-ios/issues/4681. In my case for that project I created the float labels manually.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can if you can override this method of textfield

```
 override func placeholderRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
    var rect = super.placeholderRect(forBounds: bounds)
    rect.origin.x = rect.origin.x + CGFloat(paddingyouwant)

    return rect
}
```

Comment: I tried it but doesn't works for me, I added an extension for MDCTextField but i think the MDCTextInputControllerUnderline is changing everything. It doesn't works neither the placeholder inside the textfield nor the floating one when the textfield is selected.